# creating Trigrams using LinkedHashMap java

Tags: java, hashmap, multimap, n-gram, on-duplicate-key

I am trying to create a trigram model using LinkedHashMap>
where Entry is the entry of last inputed bigram (whose structure is:
LinkedHashMap

Now the problem is, being a map it does not store multiple keys (overwrites the existing key-value pair with new key-value pair for existing key).

I am not sure whether a multimap will be useful for this or not? If so, how?

Comment: I am not sure of your requirement but are you sure that a Map is the best fit for the job ? If I get what you try to do i'll try to approach it by creating a trigramm object containing three characters (or a bigramm and a char).

Comment: Issue resolved. Created a bigram obj, and used a LinkedHashMap<String,bigramobj>....

Comment: Shouldn't a char be more appropriate than String ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every collections that implements `Map` interface keeps it's keys in `Set` implementation. Set can not keep multiple values.

Multimap is just a `Map<Key, Collection<Value>>`. It allows to keep multiple values under one key.

[Read more about Maps.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html)